# yii form question

Tags: php, yii

in the yii documentation it says:

```
foreach($_POST['LoginForm'] as $name=>$value)
{
    if($name is a safe attribute)
        $model->$name=$value;
}
```

what does the array LoginForm come from? which attribute is it coupled to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, $_POST contains the input fields 'posted' from an HTML form.

In an HTML form, items have names

```
Address: <input type='text' name='LoginForm[addr]'>
City: <input type='text' name='LoginForm[city]'>
ST: <input type='text' name='LoginForm[st]'>
```

So when PHP provides this input to the script it makes the input into an array by the names, which you can iterator over with the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

The $_POST Array? if so that is a reserved/predefined variable, and it contents is usually that of the result of submitted forms. Is this what you are asking?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php

Comment: no cause i got an answer now from their forum. they used a html helper class that would give assign all the form element attributes inside an array for easier looping through functionality in php:)